# Shouldn't everything under signal-processing , fft move to dsp.stackexchange?

Tags: feature-request

There are dozens of questions which are supposed to be posted under dsp.stackexchange but posted under stackexchange.com , most of them i've found so far has a common tag as 'signal-proessing' , 'matlab' , 'fft' etc.

for instance have a look :-> 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing?sort=unanswered&pagesize=15

Shouldn't be these question moved to dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: How new are they, are they unanswered?  And stackexchange doesn't have any answers per se, the sub sites (and the trilogy) do.

Comment: there are so many unanswered, have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing?sort=unanswered&pagesize=15
i am quiet sure this question would have answered by now if posted under dsp

Answer (score 2):

No, we don't want a sudden deluge of old questions where we don't even know if the OP is around to respond to comments or acknowledge answers, etc. Besides, not all questions tagged [signal-processing](/questions/tagged/signal-processing) should be migrated because some of them are explicitly about coding an algorithm in a particular language.

If you're really concerned about these questions and want to help out, then consider leaving them a comment informing them that a Signal Processing site exists (and is over a year old!) and that they might have a better chance at getting an answer there. Also let them know that if they so choose to ask again on DSP, then they should delete their question here. That way, it solves the problem with zero complications.